# How can "typedef" make my code portable?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, avr

I read that most programmers use typedef to ensure the portability.

when I write for example:

`typedef int int16_t`

```
typedef unsigned int uint16_t
```

As long as int16_t is the same as int (the only change is the name) so where is the portability here?! why shouldn't I use int directly ?!

another question: On different microcontrollers the size of int isn't constant, for example in `AVR 32` size of int = 4 byte, while in `AVR 8-bit`, size of int = 2 bytes

What does it depend on and why does it change with the change of microcontroller?!

Comment: `typedef int int8_t` is both useless and false. `int` is always at least 16 bits. To get the proper `typedef` for `int8_t`, include the header `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: it isn't the problem, I edited it by the way

Comment: Exact bit-width of `int` is platform specific, and optionally provided by an implementation via `<stdint.h>`. `int16_t`, `int32_t`, etc, are not *required* to be provided per C99 7.20.1.1. A minimal set of "least" and "fast" typedefs *are* required, however. That said, 7.20.1.1-3: "These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of type `int` is not exactly specified by C, it is only supposed to be at least equal to 16 bits. So, on some processor architecture, compiler implements it as 16 bits whereas on some other as 32 bits. So, if a programmer writes `int a`, it would take 2 byte on the 1st architecture and 4 byte on the second -- i.e. non-uniform behavior across platforms (lack of portability considering the 'size' aspect).

To avoid that, the types are defined using names like `uint_16` or `uint_32` in some global header files (say, types.h). Inside types.h, the user-defined types would be correctly mapped to the suitable native type -- and there may be processor specific defines in types.h. e.g. considering your example:-

```
#ifdef AVR_32
typedef unsigned int  uint_32
#else
typedef unsigned long uint_32  
#endif
```

Later, a programmer would use these types(uint_16, uint_32 etc.) and won't bother about the size himself.

Comment: I disagree with the blanket statement that the different int sizes makes code non-portable. In some cases it is actually what you want, and in fact in some cases this different size of data types makes the code portable. However in cases where you specifically want 32bits (or 16 or whatever) then typedef can be used to ensure that your type is always the correct size on all platforms.

Comment: Nowhere in the C standard is `int` constrained to be at most 32 bits wide.

Comment: I agree with Chris.  The definition of portable is in the eyes of the beholder, if your definition is you want a variable to be exactly this many bits wide, then use one method.  if your definition is you want to use the generic int size whatever it turns out to be for performance or other reasons, use int.  uint_32, etc is the former type of portability but not the latter.

Comment: What is a use case that different int sizes make the code portable?

Comment: @larsmans: Corrected it. My idea was sizeof(int) should be <= sizeof(long). However, max range of long is also not constrained.

Comment: @Chris: Edited and mentioned what kind of portability I meant here. Could you show an example how different 'int' size can contribute to portability?

Comment: Differently-sized `int` doesn't aid portability that much, but the varying size of `size_t` does: it allows indexing of whatever array size the platform supports.

Comment: The example the OP uses in regards to processor registers, if you write a program that reads an AVR register into int8_t then move that code to AVR32, it won't work, but if you read the same register into int, and move to avr32, then it will work. Another pitfall of typedef int types, is that people frequently make a fixed size typedef (32bits for example), and then store memory addresses in it, which obviously won't work when you move to a platform with 64bit addresses.

Answer (score 3):

The name of the type `int16_t` implies that you want a 16-bit signed integer. This is not true for the type `int`; its implementation depends on the compiler, which in turn depends on the platform.

So you use `typedef` to gain the flexibility of using conditional definitions.

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_A
typedef int int16_t;
#else // any other platform
typedef short int16_t;
#endif
```

The number of bits in the standard integer type usually depends on the size of the CPU registers and the width of the data bus between the CPU and the memory. So, generally, you can assume that an `int` has the most effective size that your CPU can handle.

Comment: Also, oftens this kind of `typedef`s is generated automatically by the build system, which either knows the target platform or does its checks (e.g. with `sizeof`), determines the appropriate types and spits out the header with the correct definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Typedefs in the context of portability are generally used in preprocessor macros with conditional compiling:

```
#if defined(INTEL_PROCESSOR)
typedef int my_desired_integer;
#elif defined(POWER_PC)
typedef long int my_desired_integer;
#elif defined(SOME_OTHER_WEIRD_PROCESSOR_OR_OS)
typedef short int my_desired_integer;
#endif
```

Then you use `my_desired_integer` everywhere in your code and the preprocessor will make sure to put the right type into the typedef.